# sound problem, spikes, help please

Tags: 12.04, sound, hda-intel

I have problem with sound. I have just installed **12.04 64 bit**, and sound is so bad, got *spikes* on sound(youtube, mp3, avi...), like when CD have scraches.
In the settings `analog output` is `analog stereo duplex`.
I think that this problem is only on 12.04 and linux mint 13

Here is my card info:

```
 0 [SB             ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI SB
                      HDA ATI SB at 0xfe024000 irq 16
 1 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
                      HDA ATI HDMI at 0xfdefc000 irq 44
```

And cat /proc/asound/card*/codec#*:

```
Codec: Realtek ALC888
Address: 3
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x10ec0888
Subsystem Id: 0x1458e601
Revision Id: 0x100001
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
GPIO: io=3, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=1, wake=0
  IO[0]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[1]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[2]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
Node 0x02 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x11: Stereo
  Device: name="ALC888 Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Converter: stream=8, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Node 0x03 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x11: Stereo
  Converter: stream=8, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Node 0x04 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x11: Stereo
  Converter: stream=8, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Node 0x05 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x11: Stereo
  Converter: stream=8, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Node 0x06 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x211: Stereo Digital
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Default PCM Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
  Device: name="ALC888 Digital", type="SPDIF", device=1
  Converter: stream=8, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x5e0]: 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0x1e]: 16 20 24 32
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Node 0x07 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x08 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10011b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Capture Switch", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
  Device: name="ALC888 Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x0b, nsteps=0x1f, stepsize=0x05, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x12 0x12]
  Converter: stream=4, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0x6]: 16 20
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Connection: 1
     0x23
Node 0x09 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10011b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Capture Switch", index=1, device=0
  Control: name="Capture Volume", index=1, device=0
  Device: name="ALC888 Analog", type="Audio", device=2
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x0b, nsteps=0x1f, stepsize=0x05, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0x6]: 16 20
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Connection: 1
     0x22
Node 0x0a [Audio Input] wcaps 0x100391: Stereo Digital
  Control: name="IEC958 Capture Switch", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Capture Default", index=0, device=0
  Device: name="ALC888 Digital", type="SPDIF", device=1
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0x1e]: 16 20 24 32
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x1f
Node 0x0b [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Rear Mic Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Rear Mic Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Front Mic Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=1, ofs=0
  Control: name="Front Mic Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=1, ofs=0
  Control: name="Line Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=2, ofs=0
  Control: name="Line Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=2, ofs=0
  Control: name="CD Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=4, ofs=0
  Control: name="CD Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=4, ofs=0
  Control: name="Beep Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=5, ofs=0
  Control: name="Beep Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=5, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x17, nsteps=0x1f, stepsize=0x05, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 10
     0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1c 0x1d 0x14 0x15 0x16 0x17
Node 0x0c [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Control: name="Front Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x1f, nsteps=0x1f, stepsize=0x05, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x1f 0x1f]
  Connection: 2
     0x02 0x0b
Node 0x0d [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Control: name="Surround Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x1f, nsteps=0x1f, stepsize=0x05, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x1f 0x1f]
  Connection: 2
     0x03 0x0b
Node 0x0e [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Control: name="Center Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="LFE Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=2, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x1f, nsteps=0x1f, stepsize=0x05, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x1f 0x1f]
  Connection: 2
     0x04 0x0b
Node 0x0f [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Control: name="Side Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x1f, nsteps=0x1f, stepsize=0x05, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x1f 0x1f]
  Connection: 2
     0x05 0x0b
Node 0x10 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x11 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x12 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x13 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x14 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Control: name="Front Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Line-Out Front Jack", index=0, device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x0000003e: IN OUT HP Detect Trigger
  Pin Default 0x01014410: [Jack] Line Out at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Green
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=02, enabled=1
  Connection: 5
     0x0c* 0x0d 0x0e 0x0f 0x26
Node 0x15 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Control: name="Surround Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Line-Out Surround Jack", index=0, device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x0000003e: IN OUT HP Detect Trigger
  Pin Default 0x01011412: [Jack] Line Out at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x2
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=03, enabled=1
  Connection: 5
     0x0c 0x0d* 0x0e 0x0f 0x26
Node 0x16 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Control: name="Center Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="LFE Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=2, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Line-Out CLFE Jack", index=0, device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00000036: IN OUT Detect Trigger
  Pin Default 0x01016411: [Jack] Line Out at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Orange
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x1
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=04, enabled=1
  Connection: 5
     0x0c 0x0d 0x0e* 0x0f 0x26
Node 0x17 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Control: name="Side Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Line-Out Side Jack", index=0, device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00000036: IN OUT Detect Trigger
  Pin Default 0x01012414: [Jack] Line Out at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Grey
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x4
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=05, enabled=1
  Connection: 5
     0x0c 0x0d 0x0e 0x0f* 0x26
Node 0x18 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Control: name="Rear Mic Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Rear Mic Jack", index=0, device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0000373e: IN OUT HP Detect Trigger
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  Pin Default 0x01a19c40: [Jack] Mic at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Pink
    DefAssociation = 0x4, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x21: IN VREF_50
  Unsolicited: tag=06, enabled=1
  Connection: 5
     0x0c* 0x0d 0x0e 0x0f 0x26
Node 0x19 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Control: name="Front Mic Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Front Mic Jack", index=0, device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x03 0x03]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0000373e: IN OUT HP Detect Trigger
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  Pin Default 0x02a19c50: [Jack] Mic at Ext Front
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Pink
    DefAssociation = 0x5, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x24: IN VREF_80
  Unsolicited: tag=07, enabled=1
  Connection: 5
     0x0c* 0x0d 0x0e 0x0f 0x26
Node 0x1a [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Control: name="Line Jack", index=0, device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0000373e: IN OUT HP Detect Trigger
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  Pin Default 0x01813c41: [Jack] Line In at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Blue
    DefAssociation = 0x4, Sequence = 0x1
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=08, enabled=1
  Connection: 5
     0x0c* 0x0d 0x0e 0x0f 0x26
Node 0x1b [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Front Headphone Jack", index=0, device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x0000373e: IN OUT HP Detect Trigger
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  Pin Default 0x02214c20: [Jack] HP Out at Ext Front
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Green
    DefAssociation = 0x2, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0xc0: OUT HP VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=01, enabled=1
  Connection: 5
     0x0c 0x0d 0x0e 0x0f 0x26*
Node 0x1c [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400001: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x9933014f: [Fixed] CD at Int ATAPI
    Conn = ATAPI, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x4, Sequence = 0xf
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
Node 0x1d [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400000: Mono
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
Node 0x1e [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400300: Mono Digital
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x014b1130: [Jack] SPDIF Out at Ext Rear
    Conn = Comb, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Connection: 1
     0x06
Node 0x1f [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400200: Mono Digital
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x01cb6160: [Jack] SPDIF In at Ext Rear
    Conn = Comb, Color = Orange
    DefAssociation = 0x6, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
Node 0x20 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00040: Mono
  Processing caps: benign=0, ncoeff=17
Node 0x21 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x22 [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Input Source", index=1, device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 11
     0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1c 0x1d 0x14 0x15 0x16 0x17 0x0b
Node 0x23 [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Input Source", index=0, device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x00 0x00] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 11
     0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1c 0x1d 0x14 0x15 0x16 0x17 0x0b
Node 0x24 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x25 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x11: Stereo
  Converter: stream=8, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Node 0x26 [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x1f, nsteps=0x1f, stepsize=0x05, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x1f 0x1f]
  Connection: 2
     0x25 0x0b
Codec: ATI R6xx HDMI
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 0)
Vendor Id: 0x1002aa01
Subsystem Id: 0x00aa0100
Revision Id: 0x100100
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x70]: 32000 44100 48000
    bits [0x2]: 16
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
GPIO: io=0, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=0, wake=0
Node 0x02 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x201: Stereo Digital
  Converter: stream=1, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled GenLevel
  Digital category: 0x2
Node 0x03 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400381: Stereo Digital
  Control: name="HDMI/DP,pcm=3 Jack", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="ELD", index=0, device=3
  Pincap 0x00000094: OUT Detect HDMI
  Pin Default 0x18560010: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=01, enabled=1
  Connection: 1
     0x02
```

My speaker is in black jack.

How can i fix this ? Thanks

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: i edited post, do you need more info ?

Answer (score 2):

### Compile driver

1. Go to [Realtek official site](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsCheck.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false), accept the disclaimer, then download the audio driver for linux/unix. You need to select version 3 for Kernel 3 or later.
2. Setup necessary tools to compile this driver.

   `sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc make`
3. Extract the downloaded file, run `./install` file from a terminal after going to the extracted folder to compile the driver.
4. Read the `Readme.txt` file for more information.

I had a problem with Sound settings in Ubuntu 12.04. It fixed now

---

### Solution 2

I have just found another solution:

*(It worked for me with Only S/PDIF profile, Sound from both headphone and speaker and not being able to switch profile)*

1. Add this ppa by the command

   `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily`

2, Update packages list. by 
 `sudo apt-get update`

1. Then install "alsa-hda-dkms" package:
   `sudo apt-get install alsa-hda-dkms`.

Reboot, And See the result!

Comment: Still same. But I noticed, that, when i set Analog Stereo Output, and when that sound spike happens, it change to Analog Stereo Duplex :(

Comment: @mirzadelic i've given another option

Comment: now i got new problem, i just have usb audio device in sound settings, i dont have built in audio(jack), how can i fix this? :(